# Use object oriented on JavaScript

Tags: javascript, oop, object

I am new to JavaScript and am trying to learn how to upload images on my screen and then swap it.
The way I manage it is using the following code:

```
 for(i = 0; i <= 5; i++) { 
  N= " + i;
  document.write("<img id= " + N + " src='graphics/" + N + ".jpg' onclick='swap(id)'/>");  
}
```

However, I want to learn how to use an object orriented way to do it and work with objects, but I found it very difficult to make it work. How to use OO? Using OO, I want to use an array of 3*3 size and swap the images on mouse click.

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5608/Writing-Object-Oriented-JavaScript-Part-1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A good start is [*Working with Objects*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects) from the Mozilla Development Center(/Network).

Actually you are already working with objects, as nearly everything in JavaScript (even functions) are objects.

You also have to learn what the [*Document Object Model*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/About_the_Document_Object_Model) (DOM) is and [how it connects to JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/The_DOM_and_JavaScript).

And it is not wrong to read the whole [MDC JavaScript guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide), especially about functions as functions are very powerful in JavaScript (mostly because they are objects).

Confused now? Don't worry, read and learn :)

Comment: +1 for pointing out how important the DOM is in performing almost any UI task in JavaScript.

Answer (score 2):

This might be a good strarting point:

```
var myImage = document.getElementByID('myImage');
myImage.src = 'someurl';
```

Answer (score 2):

You could have a look at an introductive article on the [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript).

Furthermore I created this small – hopefully illustrating – example. (Notice the private method and what happens when you try to access it from "outside"!)

```
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
function Gallery() {

    // private members
    var apple   = document.getElementById('apple');
    var orange  = document.getElementById('orange'); 
    var hasSwapped = false;

    // private method
    hasSwapped = function() {
        hasSwapped = true;
    }

    // public method
    this.swap = function() {
        var swap = apple.src;
        apple.src = orange.src;
        orange.src = swap;
        hasSwapped();
    }

    // public method
    this.getInfo = function() {
        return hasSwapped ? "Swapped!" : "Not swapped!"; 
    }
}
</script>

<img src="apple.jpg" id="apple" />
<img src="orange.jpg" id="orange" />

<script type="text/javascript">
alert("Starting ...");

var gallery = new Gallery(); 
gallery.swap(); 
alert(gallery.getInfo());

if(gallery.hasSwapped()) {
    alert("Swapped?!");
}
</script>

</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

OOP with JavaScript is a bit different. Like you, I'm relatively new to this topic so I have been trying to teach myself over the past couple of months. I would recommend reading over some of the articles posted by the other users as well as some of these:

- http://eloquentjavascript.net/contents.html
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Details_of_the_Object_Model#Class-Based_vs._Prototype-Based_Languages
- [http://www.amazon.com/JavaScript-Good-Parts-Douglas-Crockford/dp/0596517742](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596517742)

You didn't really specify what exactly you wanted to do with OOP in terms of code, so I can't really provide specific code, but I highly recommend reading these articles and others that you find on the web to get a general idea of what JavaScript is like, how it works with the DOM, and how it is related to OOP.

I hope this helps.

Hristo

Comment: +1 for the link to *Details of the Object Model*. If one comes from class based OOP, inheritance and such can be really difficult to grasp.

Comment: @Felix... Thanks. When I was in this situation... I was essentially trying to mimic Java so that link provided really good examples.

Answer (score 0):

This is an simple example of how to make an object and create "methods" to it.

```
function Hej( name )//Define the function that will define your Object.
{
    //DEFINE OBJECT VARIABLES
    this.name = name;


    //DEFINE THE METHODS    
    this.Get_Name = Get_Name;

    function Get_Name()
    {
        return name;
    }
}
```

Print to console

```
xx = new Hej("kalle"); //Create a new object
console.log( xx.Get_Name() );

yy = new Hej("pelle"); //Create a new object
console.log( yy.Get_Name() );
```

In `Chrome` this will print it out to the `console`.
In Chrome you press `F12` to go to find the console.

Test the code with http://jsfiddle.net/